# How do I save a string in the session with Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, session

I'm new to Spring MVC and I'm trying to figure out the appropriate way to do something that I think is very simple.

I have a simple jQuery AJAX call:

```
    var dataString = 'existingProject='+ $("#existingProject").val() + '&newProjName=' +      $("#newProjName").val();

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "manageProjects.html",  
        data: dataString            
    });
```

I want to set this user setting "project" for the session for the user.  This AJAX call is coming out of a javascript in a JS file and connecting to my Spring MVC controller.

The Controller is getting these variables, but I'm not sure what to do with it to make this data passed-in session specific.

I've googled the hell out of this topic and come across 6 different options (injected Session scoped beans with autowiring, beans with xml config and cgl-nodep libraries, HttpServlet attributes, @ModelAttribute, @SessionAttribute, etc, etc).  I tried to go with Session scoped beans and defined the following:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class UserSettings
```

...But the bean wasn't being locked down to the session.  I used @Autowire in my controller and found it was still the same instance between sessions so I clearly screwed it up.

I just want to save one freaking string!  There's got to be a 101 level easy way to do this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/request/mapping")
public ModelAndView methodName(HttpSession session,...){

session.setAttribute("testVariable", "Test Values!!");
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMestod(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("testVariable", "Test Values!!");
        return "testJsp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I set that value when I start in the AJAX call?  Is it appropriate to have a "handler" method for the AJAX call that sets the attribute in the session, then everyone else just pulls it back out?  Is that's the standard practice?

Comment: No difference, just put pass request or session into your ajax handling method.

Comment: I went with your first suggest and used HttpSession.  I accepted the AJAX call and set the attribute in the session.  Then I looked up that value in other controller operations that needed it.

It looks like the attribute is persisting across sessions.  I opened up a new tab and hit the site again and the settings from the first tab was already set in my brand new tab.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do. If you put some variable in the session, only that session will be able to access it not everyone.

Comment: That's my intent.  I expect this setting to "stick" for the single user/tab/window as long as they stay on the page or until they manually change it.

What I'm seeing is that when I set the attribute from the first tab, my second tab can "refresh" their page and see their state change to reflect what the first tab did.

Comment: use different browsers, like firefox+ie+chrome, if you open it in the same browser with different tabs, it is very likely that it will use the same session

Comment: Testing again...and that was it.  My test case was flawed because I'm a moron.  Thanks fmucar! :)